# Windows 7 update not installing two updates for many hours

Tags: windows-7-x64, windows-update

My windows 7 Update says 2 important updates are available but when i click
install updates it doesn't install the updates for many hours ! So how to fix this problem ? Should i install those two updates or just leave it as it is ?

(Note:Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 for Windows 7 x64-based Systems (KB2901983) is already installed successfully and many other security updates)

2 important updates that doesn't install:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 for Windows 7 for x64 (KB3102433)  
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3110329)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the updates, disconnecting the PC from the internet and then running the update. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates for a more detailed guide on the problems with Windows Update